# How to switch to a different Git branch without loosing changes in the current branch

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

If I'm already working in a branch and I have un-committed changes in my current branch, how to switch to a different branch without loosing changes in my existing branch?

So far `git stash` does the job, seeking opinions for better approaches if any. It seems having multiple stashes from different branches bit confusing. Is there any straightforward way of having the current branch state unchanged without intermediate commits, till I come back from another branch?

Comment: Why not just commit your changes in that branch? You can always amend the commit later

Comment: My default, instead of stash, is to commit with a message like "wip: Say what this commit does". But for some reason you want to do something else "without intermediate commits". Why don't you like the temporary commits?

Comment: @mousetail I agree, its one of the approaches. commit then amend.

Comment: @TTT Commit with "wip: Say what this commit does" works fine. The reason is to reduce the need for additional steps of committing/stashing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `git worktree` feature, which allows you to have multiple working trees associated with the same repository. With `git worktree`, you can create a new working tree for the branch you want to switch to and preserve the state of your current branch without the need for intermediate commits or stashes.
`git worktree`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, NubDev! Many or most of your 23 answers in the last two weeks appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Just commit! You can always reset to remove the commit later. I do that all the time. So:

```
git add .
git commit -mwip
git switch otherbranch
```

And then later

```
git switch firstbranch
git reset --soft @~1
# resume working
```